# Any idea why this while loop is not working?

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

```
<?php 
$username = 'Gianna';
$con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $s_table WHERE stName='$username'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $data1 = "instructor=";
        $data2 = $data1."'".$row['insName']."'".",";
        $trimmed = rtrim($data2, ",");}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have this successfully running in numerous other scripts, but for some reason it keeps returning `PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given on line 56` Line 56 is the `while` loop.

Comment: Strictly speaking, questions like "Any idea why my code not working?" are offtopic here. Nobody actually cares, but just for your info.

Comment: @Your Common Sense How should I have worded it...? For my info, of course.

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `$s_table`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I added `or die("something went wrong")` to the query, and it did die. Just cant figure out why.

Comment: An even bigger hint: `echo $s_table;`

Comment: sorry, I omitted that from the code on here. I have `include '../library.php';` in the script to link to the variable.

Comment: instead of `die("something went wrong")`, use `die(mysql_error())`

Comment: ok, its not echoing $s_table for some reason... Thank you @BurhanKhalid

Comment: **It is not about wording.** It is about question itself.

Comment: Despite the question, or wording, @BurhanKhalid was able to point me in the right direction and figure out where I was going wrong, which is what the whole point of SO is all about. So thank you to all that HELPED!

Comment: @Ben once you have solved this problem; you can answer your own question and then accept your own answer to close the question.

Comment: Again. My comment was not about help, but about rules. You just take point of SO wrong. Unfortunately, it is not your personal code review service.

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you for that. I will keep that in mind next time I have a question or need help.

Comment: Personally, I would like to see a site as a part of Stack Exchange, devoted for "help" as you mean it. But according to current site rules your question is classified as a "too localized" one, as it is not in specific programming problem but on your personal code inconsistency. And thus, as it will obviously won't help anyone else, it have to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your query probably failed, therefore $result was set to FALSE (boolean) by mysqli_query. This gives you the type mismatch in mysqli_fetch.

Answer (score 1):

simply this warning comes when the query gone false, so check your query by adding `die()`

check

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $s_table WHERE stName='$username'") or die("some problem in query");
```

you can use of `mysqli_error()` also.

Comment: it died... This exact line of code was copied from another line of code that works.

Answer (score -1):

Change 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $s_table WHERE stName='$username'");

to
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $s_table WHERE stName='$username'",$con);

see the diff?

Also, $s_table might not be correctly formatting as you expect. Try to concatenate it using 
string.variable.string style

Comment: thanks for the negative vote down, for just trying to help the OP. what a great community this is!